# Adding multi-selected files from JFileChooser to JList

Tags: java, list, jlist, jfilechooser

This code adds the correct number of files to the JList, but they only display the first file's name. Keep in mind this is for selecting multiple files.

```
    private void addFiles()
{
    String defaultDir = "C:\\";
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    chooser.setFileFilter(new FileFilter());
    setStatus("Selecting Files...");
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(defaultDir));
    if(chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        m_files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
        for(int i = 0; i < m_files.length; i++)
            m_leftModel.addElement(chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath());
    }
}
```

m_files = File[]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
m_leftModel.addElement(m_files[i].getPath());
```

Comment: Thank you sir, appreciate it. I forgot to use it as an array.